# Need a timer that updates after each finish item in a Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

right now i have implemented a timer class like this.

```
    static void DelaySec(string delayName)
    {
        switch (delayName)
        {
            case "Delay1":
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            case "Delay2":
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                break;
            case "Delay3":
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                break;
            case "Delay4":
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                break;
            case "Delay5":
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

i would like to set a delay and not a sleep between items in a listbox so my UI dont freeze.

hope someone out there who can help me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing a significant amount of work - or even simulating it - you should *not* be doing it on the UI thread. That's why your UI thread is freezing.

You should be doing it on a background thread, and using `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` or possibly `BackgroundWorker` to marshal any UI updates (e.g. changing a progress bar) back to the UI thread.

It's unclear what your timer is really meant to be doing here, but when you've worked out how to offload the work to a different thread, *then* describe what your code looks like.

Note that you could use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to interact easily with the UI thread - but it should still be event-based, rather than you running a lot of work in the UI thread. So for example, you could create a "queue" of work to do (based on the listbox item), set up a timer to fire every second, and on each timer tick perform the work - if it's short - for that one item. Between calls, the UI thread will be free to update itself.

Note that the async feature of C# 5 will mean you *will* be able to write normal sequential code like this, but that's a way off yet.

Comment: Hi Jon.. okay i just read it and it is not so clear.. what i really want is to implemented a timer class. instead of using thread.sleep() i would like to use i normal timer (delay).. i want to for example in my ListBox:

item1
insert a delay 1 sec
item2
insert a delay 3 sec
item3

does it make any sence?

Comment: @DumaSexy: Don't create your own timer class. Use one of the existing ones, and keep track of your state so you know what to do next time the timer "ticks", and adjust its delay between ticks.

Comment: It is because i want that the user to have the oppertunity to set how much delay the user want.

Comment: @DumaSexy: You can still take that into account. You just need to change the timer's "Interval" property each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...
    stopwatch.Start();
    timerLabel.Visible = true;
    progressBar1.Maximum = SequenceListBox.Items.Count;
    progressBar1.Step = (progressBar1.Maximum / SequenceListBox.Items.Count);
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    foreach(ElementControl item in SequenceListBox.Items)
    {
        item.RunElement();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    ...
```

Comment: Application.DoEvents is a hack to avoid doing it properly. It introduces reentrancy and should basically be avoided IMO.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the code is not very structured to split it into some blocks and do it separately.

Comment: okay i just need to do it 1 step at the time...
i just want to make a class timer where it will do a delay that do nothing in for example 5 sec and dont freeze my UI.. so instead of my thread.sleep(5000) just do nothing in 5 sec.

Comment: Just because something is difficult to do properly does not make it appropriate to use a hacky solution which introduces its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve. However, I am not sure whether when the stopwatch to start and stop timing. Your example seems to be start the watch multiple times and stop it only once.

```
    private int currItem;
    private List<ElementControl> Elements = new List<ElementControl>();
    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (SequenceListBox.Items.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item");
            return;
        }

        // Prevent starting again
        StartButton.Enabled = false;

        Elements.Clear();
        foreach (ElementControl ele in SequenceListBox.Items)
            Elements.Add(ele);

        // Must start stopwatch before timer to prevent timer_Elapsed from closing a non-existent stopwatch
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        stopwatch.Start();

        // Start timer
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public delegate void ReportProgressHandler(int value, string text);
    private void ReportProgress(int value, string text)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new ReportProgressHandler(ReportProgress), value, text);
        else
        {
            if(value <= progressBar1.Maximum)
                progressBar1.Value = value;
            timerLabel.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If all item process, stop timer, stopwatch and re-enable button
        if (currItem >= Elements.Count)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            ReportProgress (curItem, stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0" + " sec"));
            stopwatch = null;
            MessageBox.Show("The Test is Finish");
            //StartButton.Enabled = true;
            // Use the same approach as that used to report progress.
        }
        else
        {
            // Select item and run it
            ElementControl item = Elements[curItem];
            item.RunElement();
            currItem++;

            ReportProgress (curItem, "sometext"));
        }
    }
```

this is another possible way to do it:

```
    class Task
    {
        public List<ElementControl> Elements = new List<ElementControl>();
    }
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;

        Task task = new Task();
        foreach (ElementControl ele in SequenceListBox.Items)
            task.Elements.Add(ele);

        progressBar1.Maximum = task.Elements.Count;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(task);
    }
    public delegate void ReportProgressHandler(int value, string text);
    private void ReportProgress(int value, string text)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new ReportProgressHandler(ReportProgress), value, text);
        else
        {
            if(value <= progressBar1.Maximum)
                progressBar1.Value = value;
            label1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = e.Argument as Task;
        if (task != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ElementControl ele in task.Elements)
            {
                i++;
                ele.RunElement();
                ReportProgress(i, "sometext + " + i.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: okay i dont need to change my code.. its working fine.. the thing i want i just change my delayTimer class. so instead of thread.sleep i want to use something else that  can delay and do nothing.. or does i have to use thread.sleep? in C as i remember there is a function delay(ms)? isn't there something like that in .Net 3.5?

Comment: this is exactly what my code does. Using Thread.Sleep causes the UI to stop responding. My code allows the UI to continue responding while at the same time delay the processing of each element.

Comment: alternatively, you could do what @jon-skeet recommends. Then you can just use Thread.Sleep in the background thread.

Comment: okay i will try to make a research for the background thread.. maybe that will do the work

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng i have inserted your code and my UI froze when my sequencelist is done.. got this in debug mode.. Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.



progressBar1.Maximum = SequenceListBox.Items.Count; //exeption here

Comment: @DumaSexy, try changing your `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` but remember to `Controls.Add (timer);` before calling `timer.Start();` and `Controls.Remove(timer)` after `timer.Stop();` Hopefully this will put everything into the UI thread.

Comment: sorry that didn't work:D my code is a mess right now:D gotta clean up and start over again:D but thx anyway

Comment: will get back to you later on this. Have to finish up something else first. :D

Comment: @DumaSexy, I have changed my answer to solve the cross-thread issue. I have also added another example using `BackgroundThread`.If you didn't notice, you can actually vote up my answer and comments if you find them useful.

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng, Hi i have gone back to my old code.. because i got too confuse so i startet over again.. i will try read the code you posted tonight when i have the time.. But thank you for putting some time for me:D